# MID of string results in empty value

Tags: crystal-reports

I´m trying to convert values from database to text to get part of a string, but the result is always empty.

```
StringVar strCNPJ := CSTR({Command.numbers},10,"");
StringVar strResult;
strResult = MID(strCNPJ,1,3);
//strCNPJ
strResult
```

The result is:

[image: strResult]

Changing the variable result like this gets a string of numbers:

```
StringVar strCNPJ := CSTR({Command.CNPJDoFundo},10,"");
StringVar strResult;
strResult = MID(strCNPJ,1,3);
strCNPJ
//strResult
```

[image: strCNPJ]

Is the problem with `MID`? Did I miss a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one piece that I miss often.. you assign a variable using :=
so this line should read

```
strResult := MID(strCNPJ,1,3);
```